# mysql LIKE where clause with parameter doesn't use index

Tags: mysql

In my testing, mysql select statements with a where clause that contains a LIKE that compares to a parameter won't use an index. A full table scan is done and performance suffers. e.g.

```
set @gp1:= 'BOB%';
select * from quote where quoteNum like @gp1; -- this is slow
```

If the value is inlined the index is used. e.g.

```
select * from quote  where quoteNum like 'BOB%'; -- this is fast
```

Is there a way to force mysql to use an index in the first example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Character set and collation of the variable must be the same as the column for the query to work.

```
SET character_set_connection = latin1;
SET collation_connection = latin1_swedish_ci;
set @gp1:= 'BOB%';
select * from quote where quoteNum like @gp1; -- this is fast now
```

This answer is dealing with a similar problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15032843/176868

Answer (score 2):

Following forces index...

```
SELECT * FROM employee USE INDEX (emp_name_index)
  WHERE emp_name like 'white%';
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The output from "set @gp1:= 'JDV21501008%'; explain select * from quote use index(quoteNum) where quoteNum  like @gp1;" shows a full table scan.

Comment: To be clear, your example does work but I need a solution for parameterized queries and your solution doesn't work for that.

Comment: Unfortunately, values of variables in WHERE clause are not used to choose indexes and you have to use `USE INDEX` to help with right index. This is the same in SQL Server. What is the problem to "tell" mysql which index it has to use?

Comment: Even with USE INDEX or FORCE INDEX, the parameterized version of the query doesn't use the index. That's the problem.