# Weird Performance Issue?

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a puzzling severe MySQL query performance issue.

If I run

```sql
SET @name = 'John'
SET @customer_id = 123

SELECT full_name, address1, address2, city, state, zip
FROM   users
WHERE  first_name = @name
       AND customer_id = @customer_id
```

After an hour, the query still hadn't completed.

However,

```sql
SELECT full_name, address1, address2, city, state, zip
FROM   users
WHERE  first_name = 'John'
       AND customer_id = 123
```

would complete in 1 second.

Admittedly, the users table has over 142 million rows so it is a largish table, but the first query is behaving like a full table scan where as the second is behaving like an index seek though there is no index on the first_name column.

Any ideas? I cannot imagine why using a user-defined variable in the WHERE clause would make a query go from taking 1 second to over 1 hour!!

I would be okay with the query taking a long time as it is a large table, but I don't understand why using a variable makes the query so much slower.

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plan to see what might be the issue?

Comment: Alas, I am normally a SQL Server developer and know my way around troubleshooting performance issues in SQL Server, but in  MySQL??? Based on some Googling, I added the _explain_ keyword prior to my _select_, but it was not helpful to me. If you could point me to a resource that would show me the execution plan in MySQL a la SQL Server Management Studio, I would be grateful!

Comment: What are the data types of the the fields being compared? Since session/@ variables have less rigid typing, perhaps the first version is casting the field values for every row, rather than cast the values in the session/@ vars. Also, did you try running them in opposite order after a fresh boot, to see if the latter one was benefiting from the table being cached in memory?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql query dont't uses index when there are variables in WHERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15032843/892493)

See the part about character set. What if you change it to `... first_name = CONVERT(@name using latin1)...` or whatever charset your data is in?

Comment: @drew010, you were right. Adding the ``convert`` bit made the query complete in under 1 second. The implicit cast/conversion of 142 million rows must have been killing my query. Thank you!

Comment: @AndrewPark - The `CONVERT` should be a constant, performed once before the query starts.  (I could be wrong, due to the @).  Meanwhile, provide the `EXPLAINs` even if you don't understand them.

Comment: @RickJames, agreed, I wrote my code as `set @test_me = 'abc'; set @test_me = convert(@test_me using latin1)` THEN `WHERE column  = @test_me`. Make no sense to repeat the function execution potentially thousands or millions of times.